# Slack API: channels.create followed by channels.invite/info returns channel_not_found error

Tags: javascript, promise, slack-api, botkit

I am building a slack bot with botkit and the nodejs slack developer kit. I have a series of api calls, the first to find the users (globalMembers), the second to create a channel based on an array of channels, and a final call to add each user to each of the newly created channels.

To do this, I have several promises in order to loop through the channels and members. The channels are created successfully, and I then send unique arrays with each member and channel (`[[member1, channel1], [member1, channel2]....]`) to a promise that will invite members to the respective channel.

No matter what (I am using the channel ID) I am given the "channel_not_found" error when I try to get the channel info or invite members to that channel. I am new to promises and likely have an error there somewhere, and appreciate any help.

Below is my code:

```
var channels = ["gameplay", "gamelog", "map"];
var channelData = channels.map(channelCreate);

var channelResults = Promise.all(channelData);

return channelResults.then(created => {
    var channelMembers = [];
    _.each(created, function(channel) {
        // globalMembers is the user list
        _.each(globalMembers, function(member) {
            var array = [channel, member];
            // prints array of arrays [channel, member]
            channelMembers.push(array);
        });
     });

     var memberData = channelMembers.map(channelJoin);

     var memberResults = Promise.all(memberData);

     return memberResults.then(joined => {
        console.log(joined, "is the joined data");
     });

});


var channelCreate = function channelCreate(name) {

      // Join the channels
      return web.channels.create(name).then((res) => {
        console.log("created labyrinth channel: " + JSON.stringify(res.channel));            
        return res.channel;

      }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) }); // End channels.join call 

}; // End channel create

var channelJoin = function channelJoin(params) {

      var member = JSON.stringify(params[1]["id"]);
      var channel = JSON.stringify(params[0]["id"]);
      console.log(member, "is the member that will join " + channel);

        web.channels.info(channel).then(channelData => {
          console.log(channelData);
          if (channelData) {
            // Invite each user to the labyrinth chat channel
            return web.channels.invite(channel, member)
              .then(res => {
                return res;
              }).catch((err) => { console.log(err) });

          }
        }).catch(err => console.log(err));

}; // End channel Join
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
var channel = JSON.stringify(params[0]["id"]);
```

The value `params[0]["id"]` would be the channel ID (for example "C123456"). But when you pass it through `JSON.stringify()`, you'll end up with escaped quotes in the string (for example "\"C123456\""). Once you pass that to `web.channels.info()`, this channel will not be found.

That would solve the immediate error you see (`channel_not_found`), but you also need to fix this for `member` too, since you call `web.channels.invite()` later.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Though I can't send params[0]["id"] with the API call because slack doesn't take PHP-style array objects (foo[0]), and returns the error "invalid_array_arg" instead. I've been trying to figure out how to get around that, which is why I tried stringifying it.

Comment: Figured out the (of course) very simple answer, which was to change `JSON.stringify(params[0]["id"]);` to `params[0]["id"].toString()`. Thank you for your help in identifying the problem!